# Let a Runnable or Thread only called one time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, runnable

i've a Runnable which is called by a Background-Service. The Runnable itself is initialized as a SingleTon-Object in my FactoryManagerClass.

In my Logcat i've several Connection attempts after 1 day running within the same second.

```
06-15 12:00:52.665    9374-9656/com.myAppI/﹕ RestPushServiceRunnable: : Requesting url: http://my.ip/lp/053303932; LastModify: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; ETAG:
06-15 12:00:52.680   9374-17595/com.myAppI/﹕ RestPushServiceRunnable: : Requesting url:           http://my.ip/lp/053303932; LastModify: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; ETAG:
06-15 12:00:52.685   9374-15696/com.myAppI/﹕ RestPushServiceRunnable: : Requesting url: http://my.ip/lp/053303932; LastModify: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; ETAG:
```

This means it have it 3 times created but at least it should have been only 1 runnable running.

```
private static LPRunnable lpRunnable = null;
private static ExecutorService pushThreadPoolExecutor = null;

public static LPRunnable getLPRunnable() {

    if (lpRunnable == null) {
        synchronized (LPRunnable.class) {
            lpRunnable  = new LPRunnable (CustomService.getContext());
        }
    }
    return lpRunnable;
}

public static ExecutorService getPushThreadPoolExecutor() {
    if (pushThreadPoolExecutor == null) {
        pushThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    }
    return pushThreadPoolExecutor;
}
```

My Runnable Class is (hardly truncated)

```
public class LPRunnable implements Runnable {
public static boolean isRunning = false;


@Override
public void run() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        isRunning = true;
        URL serverAddress;

        while (isRunning) {
            try {

                MDatabaseManager databaseManager = methodToInitMYDBManager();
                PushConnection pushConnection = new PushConnection();
                pushConnection.setStatusCode(0);
                //this is used to store the last connection attempt (time)
                databaseManager.insertEntry(toContentValues(pushConnection), "pc");
                connection = null;

                serverAddress = new URL(myURLforLongPolling);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(false);
                connection.setReadTimeout(100000);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                connection.connect();
                long begin_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int resCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (resCode != 200) {
                    throw new IOException("Response Status Code not 200");
                }

                parseInputstream(connection.getInputStream());
                long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isRunning = false;
            } finally {
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                        connection = null;
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Now the interesting Part. Ive an AlarmTimer which calls another Runnable. The Runnable do some stuff and at the end it validates the connection by calling this method.

```
Future connectionFuture;

public void validatePushConnection() {
       databaseManager = myMethodToInitTheDb();
       //here it will get the last sent push
       PushConnection pushConnection = databaseManager.getLastPushConnectionFromDB();
       if (pushConnection != null) {
            long secondsSinceLastPush = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - pushConnection.getLast_connection_attempt().getTime()) / 1000);
            if ((secondsSinceLastPush >= 400 || secondsSinceLastPush == 0) && hasInternet()) {
                      Log.e("CommandManager", "Delay is larger then 400 or and internet is there. Reconnecting");
                mFactoryManager.getLPRunnable().isRunning = false;
                connectionFuture = mFactoryManager.getPushThreadPoolExecutor().submit(mFactoryManager.getLPRunnable());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("CommandManager", "No push yet. Waiting for the first push");
            if (connectionFuture  == null || connectionFuture.isCancelled() || connectionFuture.isDone() || connectionFuture.get() == null) {
                connectionFuture = mFactoryManager.getPushThreadPoolExecutor().submit(mFactoryMAnager.getLPRunnable());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

The problem is, that the Connection (Runnable) to the server seems to be created multiple times (after a while) and should be only have one instance of runnable. What may caused the multiple connections?

Answer (score 2):

The following (twice used) pattern is not so thread-safe even with that `synchronized`.

```
private static A a;

public static A getA() {
    if (a == null) {
        a = new A();
    }
    return a;
}
```

A correct pattern would be:

```
private static class AHolder { // Ensures full initialisation of the class
    private static A a;
}

public static A getA() {
    if (AHolder.a == null) {
        synchronized (A.class) {
            // The first may have filled a
            if (AHolder.a == null) {
                AHolder.a = new A();
            }
        }
    }
    return AHolder.a;
}
```

This for both static fields. Myself I'd rather not use `static` that much.

---

***Elaboration***

Above both lpRunnable and pushThreadPoolExecutor should be singletons (objects existing only once).

*(If the class containing these fields were a singleton, `static` could be removed at several spots.)*

Now `synchronized (LPRunnable.class) {` guarantees that only one thread passes, the other wait. In yyour code it means if already not null, no "synchronization" takes place and everything is fast. However if still null, while on thread is within the synchronized block (the so-called **critical region**) other threads may stop at the synchronized, If the first thread leaves the synchronized block (first lpRunnable created), the second thread enters the synchronized block, again creating a new lpRunnable.

For this reason I added a second `if lpRunnable == null`:

- The first `if` is a speed-up when `lpRunnable` is filled.
- The second `if` checks if we might no have made to wait, and an earlier thread created it alread.

Comment: Thank you, but i didnt understand it exactly. What do you mean it's nojt thredsafe? i thought synchronized will make sure that its called only onec? What is the proper way accessing making sure it's only one instance without loading it into the memory (lazyloading)? I prefer not initializing in extends Application

Comment: The first thread comes to the if-clause and starts creating the singleton instance. Meanwhile a second thread comes to the same if-clause and also starts the create the singleton because the first thread hasn't yet finished to create it. Therefore you need to lock/synchronize with this and check the if before and after getting into the sync-block.

Comment: Thank you. Ive upvoted it, but can you please explain this in your sample:

IF you say "not so thread safe". What is the synchronized used for? I thought it will lock it bound to the Class which was used in the synchronized block? Isnt it exactly the same like the second example you have posted? Since the Thread and Runnable is a loaded as SingleTon too, there shouldnt be two instances of the Runnable, shouldnt it? Is there a better way doing this?